# HTTPContext.Current in controller is null after multiple awaits

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, async-await

This is a weird one I encountered in some legacy code that I've ear-marked for re-factor. I've checked it over and the code is not using `.ConfigureAwait(false)`..

The code in question looks much like this: (The "testx = ...." lines are part of debugging the issue to expose the behaviour.)

```
public async Task<ActionResult> Index()
{
    ValidateRoleAccess(Roles.Admin, Roles.AuthorizedUser, Roles.AuditReadOnly);

    var test1 = System.Web.HttpContext.Current != null
    var decisions = await _lookupService.GetAllDecisions();
    var test2 = System.Web.HttpContext.Current != null
    var statuses = await _lookupService.GetAllEnquiryStatuses();
    var test3 = System.Web.HttpContext.Current != null
    var eeoGroups = await _lookupService.GetEEOGroups();
    var test4 = System.Web.HttpContext.Current != null
    var subCategories = await _lookupService.GetEnquiryTypeSubCategories();
    var test5 = System.Web.HttpContext.Current != null
    var paystreams = await _lookupService.GetPaystreams();
    var test6 = System.Web.HttpContext.Current != null
    var hhses = await _lookupService.GetAllHHS();
    var test7 = System.Web.HttpContext.Current != null
    // ...
```

The calls themselves are simple queries against EF through the same lookup service. Given that they are EF and use the same UoW / DbContext, these cannot be changed to use `Task.WhenAll()`.

Expected Results:
True for test1 -> test7

Actual Results:
True for test1, -> test3, False for test4 -> test7

The issue was discovered when I added a validation against a particular role after the awaited lookup calls. The check tripped a null reference exception on HttpContext.Current which the validation method uses. So it passed when used in the ValidateRoleAccess call before the async, but failed if called after all the awaited methods.

I varied the order of the methods and it failed after either 2 or 3 awaits, with no particular culprit methods.  The app is targeting .Net 4.6.1. This is a non-blocking issue as I was able to perform the role check prior to the awaits, put the result in a variable, and reference the variable after the awaits, but it was a very unexpected "gotcha" to work after 1-2 awaits, but not more. The code will be getting re-factored since the async calls aren't needed for those lookups, neither are returning the whole entities, but I'm still very curious if there is an explanation why the HttpContext would be "lost" after a couple of awaited tasks with .ConfigureAwait(false) was not used.

Update 1: The plot thickens..
I adjusted the test calls to add the test Boolean results to a List then repeated the set of loads for 5 iterations. I wanted to see if once it tripped to "False" if it ever returned to "True" at some point. My thinking is that the await was resuming on a different Thread that didn't have a reference to the current HttpContext, however no matter how many iterations I added, once false, it was always false.  So next I tried repeating the first call (GetAllDecisions) 10 times... Surprisingly the first 10 iterations all came back as True?! So I took a more close look at varying the order to see if there were calls that were reliably tripping it up, and it turns out there were 3 of them.

so for instance:

```
var decisions = await _lookupService.GetAllDecisions();
results.Add(System.Web.HttpContext.Current != null);
decisions = await _lookupService.GetAllDecisions();
results.Add(System.Web.HttpContext.Current != null);
decisions = await _lookupService.GetAllDecisions();
results.Add(System.Web.HttpContext.Current != null);
```

returned True,True,True but then changing that to:

```
var eeoGroups = _lookupService.GetEEOGroups();
results.Add(System.Web.HttpContext.Current != null);
eeoGroups = _lookupService.GetEEOGroups();
results.Add(System.Web.HttpContext.Current != null);
eeoGroups = _lookupService.GetEEOGroups();
results.Add(System.Web.HttpContext.Current != null);
```

returned False, False, False.

Digging a little deeper I noticed that the methods were a mix of EntityFramework and older NHibernate-based repository code. It was the EntityFramework async methods that were tripping up the context on await.

One of the methods that trips up the Context after an await:

```
public async Task<List<string>> GetEEOGroups()
{
    return await _dbContext.EmployeeEEOGroup.GroupBy(e => e.EEOGroup).Select(g => g.FirstOrDefault().EEOGroup).ToListAsync();
}
```

as did: *edit -whups that was a duplicate copy/paste:)

```
public async Task<IEnumerable<SapHHS>> GetAllHHS()
{
    return await _dbContext.HHS.Where(x => x.IsActive).ToListAsync();
}
```

Yet this was fine:

```
public async Task<IEnumerable<Decision>> GetAllDecisions()
{
    return await Task.FromResult(_repository.Session.QueryOver<Lookup>().Where(l => l.Type == "Decision" && l.IsActive).List().Select(l => new Decision { DecisionId = l.Id, Description = l.Name }).ToList());
}
```

Looking at the code that "works" it's pretty clear that it's not actually doing anything Async given the Task.FromResult against a synchronous method. I think the original authors were caught in the allure of the async silver-bullet and just wrapped the older code for consistency. EF's async methods work with await, but where async/await would seem to be supported with HttpContext.Current so long as `<httpRuntime targetFramework="4.5" />`, EF seems to trip this assumption up.

Comment: What happens if you comment out test1->test3 and start at test4?

Comment: Have updated the question with more detail. The culprit looks to be Entity Framework's async methods as I hadn't picked up on the mixture of EF with legacy wrapped Task.FromResult around sync calls. From what I've read async/await *should* work with HttpContext.Current, yet with EF that seems to be not the case.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In [blogs msdn](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/friis/2017/12/02/asp-net-httpcontext-in-asyncawait-patterns-using-the-task-parallel-library-part-1/) there is a full research regarding this issue and a mapping of the problem, I.E to the root of the trouble:

> The HttpContext object stores all the request-relevant data, including
>   the pointers to the native IIS request object, the ASP.NET pipeline
>   instance, the Request and Response properties, the Session (and many
>   others). Without all of this information, we can safely tell our code
>   is unaware of the request context it is executing into. Designing
>   entirely stateless web applications is not easy and implementing them
>   is indeed a challenging task. Moreover, web applications are rich of
>   third party libraries, which are generally black boxes where
>   unspecified code runs.

It is a very interesting thing to ponder about, how such a crucial and fundamental object in the program, `HttpContext` is lost during the request execution.

---

**The soultion provided:**

It consists of `TaskScheduler`, the `ExecutionContext` and the `SynchronizationContext`:

> - The `TaskScheduler` is exactly what you would expect. A scheduler for    tasks! (I would be a great teacher!) Depending on the type of .NET
>     application used, a specific task scheduler might be better than
>     others. ASP.NET uses the ThreadPoolTaskScheduler by default, which is 
>     optimized for throughput and parallel background processing.
> - The `ExecutionContext` (EC) is again somehow similar to what the name    suggests. You can look at it as a substitute of the TLS (thread local 
>     storage) for multithreaded parallel execution. In extreme synthesis,
>     it is the object used to persist all the environmental context needed 
>     for the code to run and it guarantees that a method can be
>     interrupted and resumed on different threads without harm (both from
>     a logical and security perspective). The key aspect to understand is
>     the EC needs to "flow" (essentially, be copied over from a thread to
>     another) whenever a code interrupt/resume occurs.
> - The `SynchronizationContext` (SC) is instead somewhat more difficult to    grasp. It is related and in some ways similar to the EC, albeit 
>     enforcing a higher layer of abstraction. Indeed it can persist
>     environmental state, but it has dedicated implementations for
>     queueing/dequeuing work items in specific environments. Thanks to the 
>     SC, a developer can write code without bothering about how the
>     runtime handles the async/await patterns.

If you consider the code from the blog's example:

```
   await DoStuff(doSleep, configAwait)
        .ConfigureAwait(configAwait);

    await Task.Factory.StartNew(
        async () => await DoStuff(doSleep, configAwait)
            .ConfigureAwait(configAwait),
        System.Threading.CancellationToken.None,
        asyncContinue ? TaskCreationOptions.RunContinuationsAsynchronously : TaskCreationOptions.None,
        tsFromSyncContext ? TaskScheduler.FromCurrentSynchronizationContext() : TaskScheduler.Current)
        .Unwrap().ConfigureAwait(configAwait);
```

The explenation:

> - `configAwait`: controls the ConfigureAwait behavior when awaiting tasks    (read on for additional considerations)
> - `tsFromSyncContext`: controls the TaskScheduler option passed to the    StartNew method. If true, the TaskScheduler is built from the current 
>     SynchronizationContext, otherwise the Current TaskScheduler is used.
> - `doSleep`: if True, DoStuff awaits on a Thread.Sleep. If False, it    awaits on a HttpClient.GetAsync operation Useful if you want to test
>     it without internet connection
> - `asyncContinue`: controls the TaskCreationOptions passed to the    StartNew method. If true, the continuations are run asynchronously.
>     Useful if you plan to test continuation tasks too and to assess the
>     behavior of task inlining in case of nested awaiting operations
>     (doesn't affect LegacyASPNETSynchronizationContext)

Dive into the article and see if it matches your issue, I believe you will find useful info inside.

---

There is another solution [here](https://www.trycatchfail.com/2014/04/25/using-httpcontext-safely-after-async-in-asp-net-mvc-applications/), using nested container, you can check it as well.

Comment: Thanks for the info, that's definitely provided me with a couple things to try. The first bit makes sense from deliberate multi-thread parallel-style asynchronous code, or possibly attempting to access the context from inside the awaited code, but everything I've read about async+await points to that they don't spin up a new thread for the continuation.. Though that I'm going to prove/disprove by fetching the Thread ID before & after to see.  The 2nd solution looks promising. Ultimately my goal is to cut back on the excessive async as well as the reliance on HttpContext everywhere. :)

Comment: Awesome, this nailed the coffin. The `<add key="aspnet:UseTaskFriendlySynchronizationContext" value="true" />` setting in the 2nd solution fixed the behaviour after returning from the await. I tested the thread ID before and after the awaited call and while calling an async method does not spin off a new thread, the resumption of the initial method *is* on a new thread! (which does make sense) The TaskFriendlySyncContext seems to ensure that the HttpContext is preserved upon this resumption.